# Multiple swipe event call in hammer.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am implementing  hammer.js swipe functionality to change my slider image. It's works but sometime it fire  multiple swipe event for single swipe?

When I swipe-left sometime it's fire tow swipe-left event. 
It's same for swipe-right event.

How Can I solved this problem.

```
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(el);
var pan = new Hammer.Pan();
var swipe = new Hammer.Swipe();
mc.add([ pan ]);
mc.add(swipe).recognizeWith(mc.get('pan'));

mc.on("panstart panmove", onPan);
mc.on("swipeleft swiperight", onSwipe);

function onSwipe(ev) {

    if (ev.type == 'swipeleft') 
    {
        var currentPage = $('#' + pageStepInputId).val();
        var totalPage = parseInt($('#' + pageCountLabelId).text());
        if (currentPage == totalPage) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        transform.translateX = -elParent.offsetWidth * 1.5;
        requestElementUpdate();
        $('.image-loading-indicator').show();
        $(el).one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd",function() 
                {
                    attachmentPreview.next(callComponentId, pageStepInputId, pageCountLabelId);
                });

        console.log('swipeleft', count++);
        ev.srcEvent.stopPropagation()


    } else if (ev.type == 'swiperight') {

        if ($('#' + pageStepInputId).val() >= 2) 
        {
            transform.translateX = elParent.offsetWidth * 1.5;
            requestElementUpdate();
            $('.image-loading-indicator').show();
            $(el).one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() 
                    {
                        attachmentPreview.previous(callComponentId, pageStepInputId);
                    });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code so other users can have a look at it?

Comment: I have added my code @MustangXY

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I found I was getting multiple Hammer events firing because I'd inadvertently installed multiple handlers for the same event. Worth checking that your control flow's not doing the same.